# Can you help me identify this pipe connected to the engine?

Tags: engine, maintenance, part-identification, citroen, fuel-injection

I'm confused about the pipe highlighted in blue in the picture below, can you tell me what's its role ? is it used for air ? or to pass the fuel from the injector ? I may sound talking nonsense since I really don't know anything about mechanics but I've asked two friends and I got a different answer from each.

The car is a Citroën Berlingo, petrol engine model (not diesel).
[image: The pipe location in the engine]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: year make and model, and engine size?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is line for Fuel evaporation regeneration system.

Comment: yes, thanks I just found a detailed discussion on it in a Citroën forum [link](http://www.planete-citroen.com/forum/showthread.php?t=117029) (the discussion is in french) it's used for the fuel evaporation regeneration system, it's also called a "canister".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the fuel line pipe that connects to the injectors line

Or the return fuel line its not very clear

Answer (score 0):

I can't make out for sure which line you are pointing to, however if it's connected to the Tee I have circled then it's just a vacuum line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't make the photo big,  it looks like evaporative emissions line.  It probably goes to a vent solenoid to charcoal canister